# parse_str not working on point (.) in php?

Tags: php, parsing

parse_str not working if i use . in variable how to solve this..

this function converting **.** to **_**

```
$inputString = '?test=123&ran.dom=abc&users.Lis_t=123' ;

parse_str ( parse_url ( $inputString , PHP_URL_QUERY ) , $params );

print_r ( $params );
```

this is result this converting . to _

`Array ( [test] => 123 [ran_dom] => abc [users_Lis_t] => 123 )`

please resolve my problems..

Comment: Dots and spaces are replaced with underscores. This is explained in the docs, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php under _Example #1 Using parse_str()_.